# Using CSS to create table cells of a specific width with no word wrapping

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-tables

In a project have been involved in I needed to render tables with columns of a specific width with only one HTML line per table row (no wrapping). I need each table cell to have a padding of 1 pixel at the top and bottom and 2 pixels at the left and right. The best way I can come up with that works *cross browser* is to put a div inside a td inside the table in this way:

```
<style>
  table.grid { border: none; border-collapse: collapse; }
  table.grid tbody tr td { padding: 1px 2px; }
  table.grid tbody tr td div { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; }
  table.grid tbody tr td.one { width: 100px; }
  table.grid tbody tr td.two { width: 200px; }
</style>
<table class="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="one"><div>One</div></td>
      <td class="two"><div>Two</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one"><div>Another One</div></td>
      <td class="two"><div>Another Two</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would love to be able to eliminate the need to add the extra div. I've spend many hours googling this issue but can't find an alternative.

Is there a way to do what I need without the need to add the extra div? If So, what is it?

Is there a way of getting the desired result without using tables at all?

Comment: You should add the "grid" class to the table in your example HTML to make it match your example CSS

Comment: Why do you need the div?  td is a block element after all.

Comment: Gareth, thanks, added grid to table class. cletus, I've tried overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; to td and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately table elements do not respect overflow, so you will need to apply that to a child element.

edit: I may have spoken too soon, as I can create this effect in FF using `max-width` and I've discovered [this thing](http://www.blakems.com/archives/000077.html) which might work for IE. You learn something every day.

edit2: yeah it does work for IE7 at least but there's a serious caveat that you can't have whitespace in the text, they have to be converted to `&nbsp;`. I think you should probably stick with the `<div>` solution for sake of cleanliness and compatability.

Comment: wow, thanks for the link and comments. I will stick with what I've got, but am more educated due to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: link doesn't work anymore, which is why it's customary to post the relevant content here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **you can**.

Normally, the table takes up the space it needs. If you give the `table` a 100% width, it will take 100% of the with and **share** that between the cells **regarding their contents**.

**There is no free space in a table: at some point, there must be a cell that takes up the remaining space** once the size of the others have been set.

To set a width of a cell, you would need to **give it a `width` and a `max-width` to the same size**.
For a table with N columns, you can do that to N-1 columns, and the last column will take the remaining space.

If you do that to N-2 columns, the two columns that do not have fixed with will share the remaining space.

Having this all, you can add `white-space:no-wrap` and/or `text-overflow:ellipsis` if you wish.

Here is an image example (my RSS reader) :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPpKP.png

And a live example: https://codepen.io/lehollandaisvolant/pen/REVNLy?editors=1100

You can see that it’s actually amazingly powerfull. In the codepen, you can see:

- some cells are fixed width
- some cells fit to the text it contains
- some cells fit the the container

And you can decide the behaviour of each cell (as long as there is one cell that fits to the container)

Comment: Given that the specs. does not define it for table cells, it is not recommended to use `max-width`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465385/how-can-i-set-the-max-width-of-a-table-cell-using-percentages ... whether one can or not.

Answer (score -1):

You should not need to nest a div within each table cell. The following should achieve the same affect.

```
<style>
  table.grid { border-collapse: collapse; }
  table.grid tbody tr td { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; padding: 1px 2px; }
  table.grid tbody tr td.one { width: 100px; }
  table.grid tbody tr td.two { width: 200px; }
</style>
<table class="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="one"><span>One</span></td>
      <td class="two"><span>Two</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one"><span>Another One</span></td>
      <td class="two"><span>Another Two</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried using overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; in td but it doesn't seem to work *cross browser*.

Comment: why would addign naked spans do anything? let alone improve on adding divs?

Answer (score -3):

You can also simply replace table by div.

Then you have to define the column width in CSS (which may be tricky to get to work across all browsers).

Example: Your code would then look like this:

```
<div class="mainBoxOfTable">
    <div class="Line">
      <div class="ColumnOne">One</div>
      <div class="ColumnTwo">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Line">
      <div class="ColumnOne">another One</div>
      <div class="ColumnTwo">another Two</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```