# Table cell widths - fixing width, wrapping/truncating long words

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-table

I have a table containing cells with text of various lengths. It is essential that all of the table cells are of the same width. If this means truncating long words or forcing a break in long words then that's OK.

I cannot figure out any way of getting this to work.

This is for an internal client application so needs to work in IE6 and IE7 only.

An example page is below. The cell containing `onereallylongword` is the offending one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td { width: 30px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td>word</td>
            <td>two words</td>
            <td>onereallylongword</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416401/using-css-to-create-table-cells-of-a-specific-width-with-no-word-wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416401/using-css-to-create-table-cells-of-a-specific-width-with-no-word-wrapping) Sadly, the best answer I'm aware of is wrapping the `<td>` contents in a `<div>` and applying the fixed width and overflow to that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stack Overflow has solved a similar problem with long lines of code by using a DIV and having `overflow-x:auto`. CSS can't break up words for you.

Comment: auto overflow results in scrollbars being added - in my case it looks like I will be better off using overflow: hidden.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` doesn't break up words?

Comment: It will on spaces, but not on long words that overflow.

Comment: @Diodeus what about "word-break: break-all;"

Comment: Try white-space: nowrap;

Comment: CSS Can break up words for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table

Answer (score 38):

As long as you fix the width of the table itself and set the table-layout property, this is pretty simple :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td { width: 30px; overflow: hidden; }
        table { width : 90px; table-layout: fixed; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td>word</td>
            <td>two words</td>
            <td>onereallylongword</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested this in IE6 and 7 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: That works well - however in my scenario the number of columns is variable and it will be complex for me to calculate the total width of the table.

Comment: @RichardEv As far as I have checked with Chrome, the width the be specified for the table can be anything. So, you can just set it as `0`.

Comment: Instead of using `overflow: hidden` for `<td>` I'm using `word-wrap: break-word`. Better when you don't want hide the overflow

Comment: This shit works... Specially that table-layout:fixed. I had tried all the other stuff none seem to work.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to the long text wrapped properly in new lines then in your table id call use a css property `table-layout:fixed;` otherwise simply css can't break the long text in new lines.

Comment: Just brilliant. Worked like a charm after setting this.

Comment: Please @stackoverflow, show this answer right on top. Perfect and simple solution. Just tinkered with the upper ones first and than realised this one.

Comment: This sln. is best as it allows to apply styling to the whole table and not only the content of a cell.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```css
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
overflow: hidden; 
white-space:nowrap;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
td { word-wrap: break-word;max-width:50px; }            
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize you needed a solution for IE6/7 but I'm just throwing this out for anyone else.

If you can't use `table-layout: fixed` and you don't care about IE < 9 this works for all browsers.

```
td {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

try `td {background-color:white}`

It just worked for a column I didn't want to get trampled by a previous column's long text.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work - the previous column's long text will surely cause the width of that column to expand.

Could you edit your reply to contain an example HTML snipped to illustrate?

Comment: I don't see how setting background-color to white could help here ?