# CSS line break in TD

Tags: css, word-wrap

If I have a very long string (without spaces!). Can I force the browser to line break it, for example, in a table's `td` via CSS. Width does not seem to have any effect.

*Note: I know it is very unlikely for someone to submit a long string without spaces but you never know ...*

I tried:

```
.gridrow td
{
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

and I use FF as my browser. `word-wrap` only seems to be used in CSS3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you mean is in CSS:

```
#id
{
  max-width: 100px; /*or whatever*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Tested on your site with Firebug, it works.

[Reference article](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEbreak-word.html).

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? Havbe a live example?

Comment: Please see edit in original question:


http://www.zoonosis.ac.uk/ICONZ/ResearchProjects/PublicResearchProjects?page=1

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to specify max-width.

Comment: I am no css expert but word-wrap is css3 specific is this actually suppose to be supported/official?

Comment: Most modern browsers support it, Gecko and Webkit browsers for sure, I didn't test it in IE, and I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work. CSS3 is unofficially launched but a lot of the functionality of it has already been implemented in modern browsers, like the CSS transitions in Webkit browsers. So while CSS3 is unofficial at the moment, browser developers are working hard to implement as much of it as they can.. Someone else might be able to elaborate more. www.css3.info for more information.

Comment: Word-wrap was started by IE, so yes it would support it.

Answer (score 5):

**Tables** are a special case. They'll keep on expanding if they can, so as not to obscure any content; you can't use `overflow: hidden` on them either. Here are some options:

1. Use an optional breaking character. (Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html ) If you can control insert a character like `&shy;` or `<wbr>` programatically into long strings, this may be a solution.
2. Perhaps preferably, depending on your situation, you can limit the table to use strict widths, at which point it should obey your rule:

   ```
   table {
       table-layout: fixed;
       width: 100%;
   }

   table td {
       word-wrap: break-word;         /* All browsers since IE 5.5+ */
       overflow-wrap: break-word;     /* Renamed property in CSS3 draft spec */
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. The css does not work for me. I think I might implement a business rule which prevents long words (what is too long haha). Maybe I am splitting hairs here.

Answer (score 0):

**i think there wordwrap element. search for the wordwrap.**

word-wrap: break word

EDITED

REF [Word-wrap in a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)

it suggest that there's no good way of doing this.

Comment: If there _is_ such an element, it would be semantically incorrect to use it.