# asp.net creating a table with stringbuilder, text in <td> does not wrap or break lines, runs straight off page

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a table with width of 250 px, I am creating this table using a stringbuilder, but when I add long strings to table data, the data renders as one long line, it does not stay in table.

When I use firebug I see that the table is 250 px, but data does not wrap within it.

Help pls!
thanks!

EDIT: was using whitespace:nowrap; from another CSS which was messing it all up. thx for help

Comment: Yes, I was mystified at your result, because I built a table with a stringbuilder and it wrapped just fine.  Glad to see you found your error.  As a newcomer to Stackoverflow, you should know that in such a case you would enter your answer as an answer, then Accept it.  This gives some sort of closure, and gets you a badge and some reputation points.  Just sayin' !

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent a table from expanding for long strings by giving it the style `table-layout: fixed`.

Comment: thanks but as I mentioned and verified with firebug the table itself is not expanding and is rendering at 250px.  the text in the <td></td> however, is running way past the right border

Comment: @aolle: Firebug tells you how the cell is styled. Clearly the cell is not actually 250px wide. Tables will flex unless explicitly told not to.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that you may try:

1. Inject a style into the `td` that is behaving bad: `style="word-wrap:break-word;"`
2. Check out the following to see if it helps: [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)

Hope it helps!