# Force word wrap in td tag element

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word-wrap in a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)

I have a table with two columns and specified a width. But when I put a very long string, it does not wrap. Example,

```
<table width=100% border=1>
   <tr>
       <td width=50%>  <very long string here> </td>
       <td width=50%> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The problem here that the first column with extend is I put a very long string.

Is there a CSS way to do this?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS attribute `table-layout` or `word-wrap`.

Also, refer to the following question: [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table).

Answer (score 1):

What you have works, check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PmR6F/

The columns are 50%.

If you are using large imagery or a solid line of text with no spaces your td will expand.

in this second example I have joined the text together:

http://jsfiddle.net/PmR6F/1/