# Html building problem

Tags: html, css

I built an HTML table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:1000px" id="maintable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="asc" width="30"><h3>ID</h3></th>
      <th width="200"><h3>Name</h3></th>
      <th width="200"><h3>Artist</h3></th>
      <th width="150"><h3>Album</h3></th>
      <th width="60"><h3>Time</h3></th>    
    </tr>
  </thead>    
    <tr class="evenrw">
      <td class="evensl" align="center">i++</td>
      <td align="left"><a href="link">link name</a></td>
      <td align="left">name</td>
      <td align="left">name</td>
      <td align="center">name</td>   
    <tr>
<table>
```

the problem is that when I put something in a row so that the whole table becomes bigger, Is there anyway to make the `height` of the cell bigger instead the `width` of the cell?

Comment: Try forcing a width with CSS; this should push the content together, making the cell taller to fit it all.

Comment: Check this question for answer. 

[Word-wrap in a html table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table

Comment: but the problem is that if i have a small text i only need one line,but is the text is long i need two lines for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a table width set as 1000px, and individual table columns set to a total with of around 600px. Tables a bit confusing with widths so remove the style="1000px" and that should fix the problem

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PgsCX/)

If the answer works, please mark it as the chosen answer :)

**PART TWO**

To add a banner above the table, simply add another `<div>` above the table. So it would be

```
<div id="banner_or_something">
    <!-- INSERT BANNER CODE HERE-->
</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:1000px" id="maintable">
    <!--TABLE CODE HERE-->
</table>
```

Comment: and if i have a banner in the top of the table that need to be in the same Width of the table?

Comment: Then add it in the code above so we can work with all your code.

Comment: How wide is your banner? Is it going inside the table, or above the table? Is it to go below the <thead> or above... If above, it kind of make the <thead> not a <thead> but that's another story. Can you please provide some more information....

Comment: the wide is like the table: 1000 and it is above the table

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS div & class with td tags will help you.
e.g.

```
.aaa td{
width:200px;
/* all attributes you want*/
}
```

i hope it will help you