# How to get table data content to next line?

Tags: html, css

I have a table of width 100% (fit to screen ) with 3 `<td>` in that. In 2nd `<td>` I have some content like this **addfdss212s1ssff54f5df4d54s54dsf64dsfsadjvmckjsadkjkdflsadfkksdalasdflsdfkasd6f465**, this content does not contain any space. I have given 70% of width to the 2nd `<td>` but when the characters of content increases that 2nd `<td>` expand and layout get disturb. Is it possible to get increased character to next line in width of 70% with the help of CSS?  (see below in the code).

`<table width=”100%”>`

`<tr>`

`<td width=”10%”>Result1</td>`

`<td width=”70%”>addfdss212s1ssff54f5df4d54s54dsf64dsfsaDjvmckjs
adkjkdflsadfkksdalasdflsdfkasd6f465
</td>`

`<td width=”20%”>Comments</td>`

`</tr>`

`</table>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
<tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word">LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord</td></tr>
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883702/585552

Answer (score 3):

I think the rule you're probably looking for is:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: it works but you have to put `table-layout: fixed` this style to the table tag. as per my practice.