# mobile web app with very long strings

Tags: css, word-wrap

I'm trying to build web app designed for mobiles. But I have some links which are extremely large. What i want to do is break these strings if the text doesn't fit, and use the entire string if it fits.

I tried using `word-wrap:break-word`:

```
.breakWord {
    width: 100% 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

My html is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2" style="width:10%" >picture</td>
   <td colspan="2" style="width:90%" class="breakWord">link</td>
  </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td style="width:80%">info1</td>
   <td style="width:10%">info2</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

This code doesn't fit on the page - a horizontal scroll bar appears.

How can I make the text fit?

Answer (score 0):

If you correct the errors in your source, it will work.

- Remove the `width:100%` from the style block. It conflicts with the inline style in the `td`, and misses a semicolon
- `colpan` should be `colspan`

Also, I believe that some browsers can get confused when encountering a colspanned `td` with a width style. You can safely remove the `style="width:90%"`, since the two `td`s below set the width correctly already.

**Edit:**
So it doesn't work everywhere. According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table), the problem is with the table: first, the width of the table is calculated, and then the 10% and 90% are taken as the calculated width instead of the available width on the screen.
So a possible solution is to give the table a specific width, and set its table-layout to fixed.

```
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed">
```

Comment: sry for colspan it was just a typo here, not in the code, i removed the the items you specified, but word-wrap doesn't seem to work, the table is larger than the rest of the page, and the link is displayed on a single line

Comment: Hm. Which browser do you use?

Comment: chrome and firefox, and on mobile opera and opera mini

Comment: i fixed it i added  <table style="table-layout: fixed;">

Comment: Ah, I was just doing some research and updating my answer, and I missed your comments. OK then.