# Set min-width to width of contents

Tags: css, responsive

I have a div with a background that contains a table. I want the div to have 100% width, except when that is narrower than the table is long. I can do something like this:

```css
.my-div {
  width:100%;
  min-width:900px;
}
```

That's great for a table that is 900px wide, but if it is narrower than that, I will have unwanted scrollbars and if it is wider than that, I will have content that is unreachable. Obviously, this can trivially be solved with JavaScript, but I want to know if there is a CSS-only solution, so my application isn't so JS-heavy.

For a visual of what's happening, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WTwdN/3/). What I want is for the green background to overflow the viewport when the text in the table does.

Comment: Is the 100% width in regard to the viewport width?

Comment: I don't know what that means. I want the width of `.my-div` to be equal to `document.body.offsetWidth`

Comment: The viewport is the area of the browser in which the web-page is displayed. The width of the `<body>` element is by default the same as the width of the viewport.

Comment: So the DIV should overflow the viewport?

Comment: Yes, I would like the div to overflow the viewport only when the table inside of it is wider than the viewport. I won't know the width of the table until runtime.

Comment: Is the visitor able to scroll the table/DIV horizontally? If yes, on which element is the scroll bar set?

Comment: Correction: I removed the `overflow: hidden` that someone added to the table and now there is a horizontal scrollbar, but the table spills outside the containing div. See the jsfiddle example.

Comment: The HTML code of your demo is invalid. It should be `</td></tr>` instead of `</td><tr>`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but it's not really the point. The problem persists. I think I just need to use JavaScript

Comment: That's why I wrote it in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with word wrapping.
Check this out @JoshuaClark: [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 11):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should help:

```
.my-div {
  /*width:100%;*/
  height:400px;
  background-color:#bada55;
  display: inline-block; // this is the key
}
```

Your example modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/nvLnodLh/

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```css
.my-div {
    overflow: auto;    
}

table {
    float: left;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WTwdN/4/

Comment: This makes `.my-div` scroll horizontally. I would prefer the whole window to scroll.

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is for the green background to overflow the viewport when the text in the table does.

You just wrap a table inside a table, so they both overflow.

```css
.my-div {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  display: table;
  background-color:#bada55; 
}
td {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr><td>my table</td></tr>
      </thead>    
      <tbody>
          <tr><td>my dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppppppppppppppp</td></tr>              
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you don't want your container `div` to grow bigger than viewport just set the background on the table.

```css
.my-div {
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#bada55; 
}
td {
  white-space:nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr><td>my table</td></tr>
      </thead>    
      <tbody>
          <tr><td>my dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppppppppppppppp</td></tr>              
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a draft for [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/)
 that adds `width: fit-content` which does exactly what you want. It is not supported by IE/Edge though.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this solution

```css
.my-div {
  height:400px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color:#bada55;    
}
td {
  white-space:nowrap;   
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr><td>my table</td>
          <td>my table</td></tr>
      </thead>    
      <tbody>
          <tr><td>my dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppppppppppppppp</td><td>my dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppppppppppppppp</td></tr>              
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```