# Wrapping long words in a flexible html table in Firefox

Tags: html, html-table, word-wrap, word-break

I have a table with two columns. There is a very long word in the first column. I want to have the long word wrapped.

You might have noticed this is the same issue as [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table). The chosen answer in that thread is to add 'table-layout:fixed', which means the column widths have to be fixed. But I need the table to stay flexible so that the second column only use enough width for its content when the content in the first column is too long to fit in one line.

Below [code](http://jsfiddle.net/uhZYF/) demonstrates the issue. It works well in IE/Chrome. But in FireFox, the line is not wrapped.

Has anyone got any ideas to work around this issue in FireFox?

**Update:** I just tested it in FireFox 15 Beta released 9 days before. The "word-break" is now supported by Firefox 15. But I might still need a workaround for previous versions, because it might take a while for 15 to be released and become majority.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td><div style="word-break:break-all;">LongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWord</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='#' style="white-space:nowrap;">Action</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and adding "word-break:break-all;" fixed it.  So if you will submit this as an actual answer, rather than just an "Update" to your original question, I will give your answer an upvote.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Some changes in your markup, See below code:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="word-break:break-all; word-wrap: break-word;">LongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWordLongWord</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='#' style="white-space:nowrap;">Action</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- Add `table-layout:fixed;` in table styles.
- Use `word-wrap: break-word;` with `word-break:break-all;` in `<div>` style.

**It will work on all major browsers IE, FF, Safari and Chrome.**

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8nVqX/)

Comment: A.K, thank you for the reply. But as I said, the problem with this solution is that the layout will have to be fixed. In this example, these two columns will all be 50% percent, even though the first column has much more content. I need these percentage to be adjusted based on the actual content in all the columns.