# How do you wrap log lines in a GWT custom logging area?

Tags: css, gwt

In GWT, one can create a custom logging area by installing a [`HasWidgetsLogHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/logging/client/HasWidgetsLogHandler.html). In my case, that is a `VerticalPanel`. Unfortunately, the rest of the page is distorted by the logging output, which is too wide. How can I wrap the lines?

`HasWidgetsLogHandler` adds an `HTML` element for each log entry. I tried styling the individual elements in UiBinder, but that did not work:

```
<ui:style>
  @external gwt-HTML;
  .gwt-HTML {
    white-space: normal;
  }
</ui:style>
```

Similarly, adding `overflow: hidden`—which would have been a less attractive option—had no effect.

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A VerticalPanel is implemented as an HTML table. While you can use it, I would usually recommend a FlowPanel instead.

On a FlowPanel, you can set the following properties:

```
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

`word-wrap` is CSS3, but is supported by many browsers: http://caniuse.com/wordwrap. It allows long words to be wrapped after every character. For browsers that don't support it, you may want to add `overflow: hidden`. (Or consider setting a fixed width together with `overflow: auto`.)

If you absolutely need to use a VerticalPanel, see [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table) (you have to set the word-wrap on the `<td>` then).