# How to word wrap a label's content on a specified character in ZKOSS

Tags: java, css, zk

I have a zk Label that has Value:-1,2,3,4,21,211,4321,656,1233,678,342
and due to this it does not wrap well so i tried

```
detailval.setStyle("word-wrap:break-word;");
```

which breaks it fine but i need to break it on a comma i.e. my text gets wrapped like this.

```
1,2,3,4,21,211,4321,656,1233,67
8,342

instead of

1,2,3,4,21,211,4321,656,1233,
678,342
```

Is there a way i can specify that the label gets wrapped only on one specific character.Thanks

Comment: I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574538/why-doesnt-break-word-work-on-a-long-string-with-commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css property *word-wrap:break-word;* consider that a word is anything between two spaces, in your string you don't have any of them **-1,2,3,4,21,211,4321,656,1233,678,342,** that's why it splits that string in that way you don't want, I suggest just to put a space after every comma, that will resolve your problem

**-1,2,3,4,21,211,4321,656,1233,678,342,**