# Table overflow issue

Tags: html, css

I am facing a very basic issue with table is that on overflow on `<td>` cell the text flows out of the specified width

Issue looks like something following:

```
+--------------+
| abcdef@hotmai|.com
+--------------+
```

I want that on overflow text goes to next line. Something like following.

```
+--------------+
| abcdef@hotmai|
| .com         |
+--------------+
```

I tried following css but didnot work:
`max-width:20%; table-layout:fixed;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `word-wrap` CSS property to wrap your text inside a fixed width `td`

```
table td {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I figure out one thing that its necessary to set `width` and `max-width` of the table to make `word-wrap` property work.

Comment: @softgenic you need to add width is because td will resize itself, so if you are using a fixed width for your td's so you need to wrap the text using that property so that your text doesn't overflow