# Dynamically change table height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm facing problem with table in html,
actually I fixed the **width**,and want to increase the td **height** as per the content in it,
for example : if td **width** is **30px** and when data inside td crosses the td width i want to show remaining data in **next line** and so on..

table:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="30px">
                laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa text
        </td>
            <td align="left" width="30px">
                text
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Did you try applying the `overflow: auto` CSS tag to your tds?

Comment: thans for comment,can you suggest the way of doing it.

Comment: You should check out the css property word-breakfor tables. I think it is what you are looking for. Here is a link to W3Schools about it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: place the code ` style="overflow:auto"` in your td. Try that. (BTW this implementation of CSS, inline stylesheets, is not the best, you should try using more of external stylesheets. Though this is easier for people just starting to learn CSS. You should look up CSS.)

Comment: tried overflow:auto , no luck :(

Comment: @Mike word-break breaks in the middle of words, unlike `overflow:auto`, which avoids this. Maybe that's what the OP wants, though...

Comment: Mike's answer applies if you want it to make a new line, even in the middle of words. If that's what you want, sure. `overflow:auto`, I believe only goes to the new line when there's a new word.

Comment: `overflow:auto` is not working for **td**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem! The width of the columns are equal in this case, though they can be changed, not to mention.

```
<table  border="1" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr>
<td style="word-wrap:break-word">Hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
<td>text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is the demo http://jsbin.com/ihaxob/2/edit .. 
I have seen the solution from this thread!

[Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)

Comment: give the widths in percentages.

Comment: given widths in % only, working in jsbin but not working in local ..
my case is different here .. i'm dynamically loading the table content using AJAX call

Comment: Sorry but I don't know much of AJAX.

Comment: I suggest you to modify the question since this ( the answer ) answers your question but doesn't solves your problem.

Comment: I still recommend you to modify the problem so that you can get correct answer to your problem.