# How to word wrap inside table tds?

Tags: html, html-table

The text inside my table seems to stretch 4000+px:

http://letschat.info/a-list-of-amazon-questions-and-answers-from-glassdoor/

so you can't even read the questions and answers. I tried the following:

[Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)

using table-layout: fixed

and word-wrap: break-word, but it looked the same.

I am not sure what I need to do.

Comment: make you table fixed width, provide the width in the style element, too.. like `<table style="width: 400px;">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need display "block"?

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>
<a style="width:200px;background-color:aqua;display:block"> Be yourself. Try not to be nervous, they were once in your seat too. 5) Don&#8217;t bluff anyone. Don&#8217;t try to impress them with something if you don&#8217;t know it. Be honest. In the end, it&#8217;ll help you. 6) They say check in at least 15 minutes early. I say, GET THERE 30 to 45 minutes early because there will be traffic, and taxi&#8217;s aren&#8217;t easy to get a hold of from your hotel. Sit in the lobby with other people and TALK TO THEM, relax, laugh, and enjoy it. 7) GET TO THE CHOOPPPA early. Seriously, don&#8217;t be late for your flights in or out of SEATAC. If you&#8217;re not used to SEATAC, There is a train inside the airport that will take you to your gate. TSA takes about 20 minutes to get through. Always come early. 8) Taxi&#8217;s and food are expensive, and although they do take plastic. Use cash. You don&#8217;t want to deal with a stolen credit card on trips during an interview. You don&#8217;t need the stress. If you are there   for approximately 2 nights and 3 days, or even 1 night and 2 days, take approxima
</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#table {
    word-wrap: normal; /* the default, naturally */
}
```