# setting width in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to set fixed width for cxolumns in datatable
I tried 
             
different width for all columns.
But the width changes based on the size of data . If data has space it folds down else the table width get increased.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CSS definition for your datatable. Lets call this your `p:datatable`:

```
<p:dataTable id="myDataTable" .... var="something">
  <p:column headerText="column1">
    #{something.propertyA}
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="column2">
    #{something.propertyB}
  </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Then your CSS definition must be:

```
#myDataTable.ui-datatable thead th,
#myDataTable.ui-datatable tbody td,
#myDataTable.ui-datatable tfoot td {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Links explaining `word-wrap: break-word`

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp
- [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table)

and `white-space: normal`:

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp