# Word-wrap in an HTML table using display:table-row

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table, accessibility

A more complex version of: [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table).

I'm trying to create a nice mobile version of my table. I'm using bootstrap media-queries to apply two CSS rules:

1. `display:table-row;` - This puts each cell on a new row.
2. `word-wrap:break-word;` - This makes long words go over multiple lines.

The trouble is that these two rules seem to conflict. When I use `display:table-row;`, the text does not wrap. Removing `display:table-row;` causes text to wrap again.

Is there any way I can use both `display:table-row;` and `word-wrap:break-word;`?

jsfiddle with code: http://jsfiddle.net/q46Vd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `word-break: break-word` instead of `word-wrap: break-word`.

Comment: I decided to look into this, and it may be webkit-only. :/

Comment: 'word-break: break-all' is more correct and seems to work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I replaced `display:table-row` with `display:block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/q46Vd/1/

Comment: `display: table` may also work. `table-row` has *strange* properties like no background, margin, padding (at least on Firefox and/or spec). An element styled as table or table-cell can see these properties applied (except margin on cells). It also confers [Block Formatting Context](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/) that have interesting effects alongside floats (that you may or may not want!)