# CSS override white-space:nowrap on a website

Tags: html, css

A website that I use on a regular basis does this. This causes way to much stuff to be on a single line and it goes off the screen. It needs to do word wrapping but what see below prevents it.

```
div.dbThreadDetailTreeRowCellItem {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258512/985898

I don't want to have to open firebird and fix it every time I go to the website. Is there hopefully an easy way to fix this with your css files? I am using firefox.

https://superuser.com/a/295806/93715

Firefox User Profile Folder --> Chrome -- > userChrome.css

I added this to my userChrome.css file. What do I need to add to my css file?

```
.break-word {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
-moz-hyphens: auto;
p
{
white-space:normal;
} 
.u_nowrap {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
pre { white-space: pre-wrap !important; }
```

Is there also a way to fix this issue in Chrome?

Comment: So this is about setting up a user style sheet in a browser? I think you should say that clearly at the start, and I wonder whether it is on-topic at SO.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like any of your css rules apply to the container you said is causing the problem.

Try adding this line:

```
div.dbThreadDetailTreeRowCellItem{ word-wrap: break-word !important; white-space: normal !important; }
```

Comment: Now the fun begins... Do you know if firefox is detecting your custom stylesheet? If not try making a crazy change like "body{ font-size: 10000px !important; }". Something tells me it won't. If it doesn't try renaming the "Chrome" folder to "chrome".