# "word-wrap:break-word" doesn't work when generating PDF with SpraedPDFBundle

Tags: html, css, symfony, pdf, twig

I'm trying to break a text inside a `<td>`. I tried some solutions poroposed but it seems none of them works.

> Possible Duplicate:
>   [Word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table)

I want to break a big link. Here's my code:

```
<div style="padding-top: 250px;  margin-right: 25px;">
        <table style="table-layout:fixed; width:700px;">
            <col width="300">
            <col width="10">
            <col width="10">
            <col width="10">
            <col width="10">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="desc">Link</th>
                    <th class="unit">Price</th>
                    <th class="qty">Amount</th>
                    <th class="service">TVA</th>
                    <th class="total">TOTAL</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="desc" style="overflow:hidden; word-wrap: break-word;
                            word-break: break-all;">Link</td>
                        <td >price</td>
                        <td >amount</td>
                        {% if oProd.tva %}
                            <td>tva%</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td>TVA non existante</td>
                        {% endif%}
                        <td>inal_price</td>
                        {% set total = total + final_price%}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2">Prix final</td>
                    <td>{{ total }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Now here's my CSS for desc:

```
    .service .desc h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.service .desc {
    padding: 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
table .desc {
    text-align: left;
    background: #D0D0D0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS for `.desc` and you could try specifying column widths using either `60%` or `300em` etc.  On a separate note this might improving browser compatibility
`td {  white-space: pre; /* CSS 2.0 */  white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */  white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3.0 */  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */  white-space: -hp-pre-wrap; /* HP Printers */  word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5+ */  
}  `
 [source](https://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/)

Comment: try this: `table tr td, table tr th {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }`

Comment: @Mousey do you think I'm overwitten something?

Comment: @Matteo that did not work for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi @BesbesRiadh, sorry i use the [knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle) and my comment is the solution at the same problem but with that bundle....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Besbes Riadh the code I posted will make `word-wrap: break-word` work for *different browsers* and *different versions of CSS*. It can be added to the end of your CSS. 
[Explanation and source](https://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/)

Comment: I did get back to this problem now and your solution worked fine! Now I'm trying to make my site responsive, I hope that this doesn't make my fields look crowded.