# width attribute in table not working

Tags: html, css

My code is  this :

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
    <table width="100%" border="2px solid blue">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:30%">Player</td>
            <td style="width:30%">Club</td>
            <td style="width:30%">Country</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:30%">HazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazard</td>
            <td style="width:30%">Chelsea</td>
            <td style="width:30%">Belgium</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ronaldo</td>
            <td>Real Madrid</td>
            <td>Portugal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Messi</td>
            <td>Barcelona</td>
            <td>Argentina</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The result is this :

[image: html table]

I tried to add width=30% in the column `player`, but it's still not working.

Comment: The cell is held open by your extremely long word as it has nowhere to break. In a real-world case your table would probably be fine but if you need to force a ridiculously long word to wrap you can use `word-wrap:break-word;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table

Answer (score 7):

it's beacause your text is too large 
use this may help you

```
<style>
table tr td
{
  word-break: break-all;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Moob was before me, use word-wrap:break-word;  but also use table-layout:fixed

css code

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because "HazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazardHazard" is stretching it.

Table cells will stretch to fit their content, and if they can't break, they will keep stretching.

If it was "Hazard hazard..." etc with spaces, it would break as expected. The same would happen if you put a large image in the table cell.