# Large text going out of table in td's

Tags: html, css

I'm populating a large amount of text within `td`. I am trying to wrap the text with `td` if the text content takes up enough space, but the text keeps breaking out of the table.

```
td.noBorder {
    border: none;
}
.alignTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 13px Calibri;
    color: #5a5a5a;
}
table tr td {
    height: 30px;
    border: solid 1px #cbd0d2;
}
```

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
  <div style="width:730px; margin:0 auto;">
    <h1 style="height:20px;font:normal 18px Calibri;color:#010101;font-weight:600;border-collapse: collapse; margin-left:20px"> Related Links </h1>
    <div style="width:730px; margin:0 auto;">
      <h2 style="padding-left:23px;"> Header </h2>
      <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="alignTable" >
        <tr>
          <td class="noBorder" style="text-align: left;padding-left: 23px;"><!-- #06999c --> 
            <img src="images/arrow.png" width="5" height="10" alt="" /> <a style="padding-left: 8px;" href="{$hyperlink}" target="_blank"> LARGE TEXT </a></td>
          <td class="noBorder"/>
          <td class="noBorder"/>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't be lazy. Create a working example. Use a snippet

Comment: You might find [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table) helpful

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1: Make It Scrollable**

You can make the `td` automatically scrollable if the content exceeds its regular size by setting its `overflow` property to `auto`. If you expect that the `td` will usually overflow its boundaries, you could also pass `overflow: scroll` so that it always renders with a scrollbar. Check out the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) if you decide to go that route.

**Solution 2: Flexbox**

Within the `td`, you could add a `div` and give it `display: flex`. Doing this would allow you to apply styles solely to that `div` without breaking outside of the table. This goes against the cascading principle of CSS, but should be a convenient workaround if that's all you need.

If you're unfamiliar with flexbox styles, [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) does a good job of explaining them. Flexbox is supported by [nearly all](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) modern browsers, and can be coaxed to work with IE9 and 10 if you apply [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

**Suggestion: Refactor Your Markup**

Just so you're aware, using a table-based layout is no longer a recommended way to structure most websites. If it's at all possible to refactor this into `div`'s, doing so will keep your stylesheets organized and manageable.

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities, one to add vertical scroll if text exceeds the margin, one to adjust the font size to fit the text inside, you should see what fits best in your page. If you create a snippet here I can help you more precise!