# occasional table width expansion

Tags: html, css

One of my sites is a YouTube search engine. It has a main table with a width of 750 that works normally until the text accompanying a video in a below table is a single word longer than 48 characters (which usually happens in some really long URL), then the entire main table expands to 793 and it looks weird because the logo image at the top remains at 750 pixels (the footer at the bottom also looks funky when this happens).

Is there any way to force this table to remain at 750 no matter what the length of some long word or URL in a table below it?

Comment: What do you want to happenm to the too-long word? Truncation, hyphenation, etc?

Comment: Also, you should post a snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `white-space: break-word`, perhaps?

Comment: I guess truncation would be OK, it doesn't really matter to me as long as the table width isn't messed up. I tried to post a snippet, but it didn't work and I thought maybe it wasn't allowed.

Comment: godfrzero: where would I insert the "white-space: break-word," in the "table width=750 border="0" align=center cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0", or somewhere in the CSS?

Comment: It'd be on whatever is wrapping the text. Ideally, I'd need a snippet to hammer out a proper answer :D

Comment: *I tried to post a snippet, but it didn't work and I thought maybe it wasn't allowed.* It's allowed. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: I looked at the example, my situation is I have a vertical column of tags and ads on the left, then a column on the right with the videos and descriptions. I inserted "table-layout: fixed...", etc., into the css and that really messed things up, lol.

Also, I tried inserting "td word-break: break-word" like someone else suggested, and that didn't do anything.

Here is my css if anyone wants to look at it:

https://jsfiddle.net/super70s/yzxomyoq/

Comment: I think I got it guys!

I inserted...

<td width="602" style="word-break:break-all;">{description}</td>

...into a file called list_by_tag.html

That works, at least in Firefox.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table?rq=1