# How to break long words in the text without breaking short words

Tags: css, width, css-tables, word-break

I have an HTML table cell with a text. The text has long and short words. I need to arrange a text in a way, that long words that do not fit into cell's width are broken, but short words are not broken and just moved to the next line.
But when I apply css property "**word-break: break-all;**" it breaks both long and short words. When I apply "**word-wrap: break-word;**" property, it for some reason does not break long words and the cell's width stretches automatically.

**word-break: break-all** Here all words are broken where not necessary, and the text is ugly:
[image]

**word-wrap: break-word** Here nothing is broken, but the cell width is stretched:

[image]

I want to have something like this, where only a long word is broken and table cell width stays as it is:

[image]

So that only a long word is broken and the width is not changed. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table