# CSS: break long words without breaking small words Internet Explorer 11 in anchor element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Basically I want to do what it says here: [How to break long words in the text without breaking short words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578759/how-to-break-long-words-in-the-text-without-breaking-short-words) with the text of an **anchor element**,
using Internet Explorer 11,
I already tried a lot of combinations of:
`word-break:break-all;`
`word-break: break-word;`
`word-wrap: break-word:`
From this question:
[Internet Explorer 11 word wrap is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149715/internet-explorer-11-word-wrap-is-not-working)
 I know that I should add `white-space: pre-wrap` property to my code which I already did. Still, this is not working for me.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody class="tBody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>
             <img src="image.png">
              <a href="">This is a verrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrryyyyy long
                      text that doesnt work like I want it to. I hate IE.
              </a>
          </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: inline-table;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  word-break: break-all;
 }
```

Comment: Where's your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work, I added this to my CSS file:

```
table,td,th, td *, td a, td img {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```