# word wrap not found in css template options

Tags: html, css

I am not able to find word-wrap in my CSS templates.  What could be the reason for there being no word wrap?  And how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. What do you mean when you say that `word-wrap` is not found in **CSS** template options? What is this template you speak of?

Comment: @MatthewBeckman If I use <td style= "option">, I get CSS template proposals that I can use .I am not able to find word-wrap that I need to use in the above list of proposal .I guess it might be the reason that word wrap is not working in my code .

Comment: You should really link to the CSS templates your referring to.

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to auto-complete in your text editor or IDE. Am I correct? `word-wrap` is a CSS3 property so your text editor/IDE might not have the latest CSS properties. You might have to update your editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word-wrap` on `td` elements. I'm *guessing* you are using software that waits for you to type <kbd>option</kbd> and then lets you select from the options.

You can see the **working example** below, or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883702/3230030) for more information. The important part below is `table-layout: fixed` along with the `word-wrap` on the `td` element.

## Working Example

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="word-wrap: break-word">
      LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord
    </td>
    <td style="word-wrap: break-word">
      LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: -I tried this code but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: @shweta You will have to post your code than. Make a working example, and append it to your question.