# word-wrap in a CSS grid

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, css-grid

`word-wrap: break-word` doesn't work in a grid.

[For tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table) there is `table-layout: fixed`, what is the equivalent for grids?

```html
<div style="background: #e3e3e3; width: 75%;">

 <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">
   normaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldivnormaldiv
 </div>
 
 <table>
   <tr><td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
     badtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtable
   </td></tr>
 </table>
 
 <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
   <tr><td style="word-wrap: break-word;">
     fixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtablefixedtable
   </td></tr>
 </table>
 
 <div style="display: grid;">
   <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">
     griddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddiv
   </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to the grid item.

Comment: @Michael_B: Thanks, but that doesn't fix it entirely, the wrapped part is dispalyed as overflowed text over the next grid item.

Comment: There was only one grid item in your code sample. Consider posting a more complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/j51vpsmj/

Comment: @Michael_B, sure: https://jsfiddle.net/j51vpsmj/1/

Comment: Re-size the window. There's no overflow of the second item: https://jsfiddle.net/j51vpsmj/2/

Comment: @Michael_B: Oh, that looks OK in Chrome, that must be a bug in Firefox. Thanks again.

Comment: This definitely appears to be a bug in FF. As though the `min-width` override gets applied *after* the browser has completed sizing the grid item.

Comment: [Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356820) fixed in Firefox 54.

Comment: Add both `word-wrap: break-word` and `overflow: hidden` to the grid item. Interestingly, in a grid item without `overflow: hidden`, the `word-wrap: break-word` does not seem to work at all.

Comment: I had a similar problem... refer the following js fiddle it seems to solve it

https://jsfiddle.net/7y2wofz0/

Answer (score 0):

You cant use it in td but you can add another div inside td. However, you have to give some width to break the words.

```html
    <div style="background: #e3e3e3; width: 75%;">

         <table>
           <tr><td>
            <div style="width:200px;word-wrap: break-word;"> badtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtablebadtable
            </div>
           </td></tr>
         </table>

      <div style="display: grid;">
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word;width:200px;">     griddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddivgriddiv
      </div>
      </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't limit width, it has to be auto or 100%.

Comment: I dont think you can do it otherwise since the browser has to know the width to break the word somewhere. But you can maybe use javascript at the end to set the width