# word-wrap not working in a CSS Grid item

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a paragraph text without line breaks. It is supposed to be wrapped to a new line if the width exceeds the width of the grid container. It works if the container is not a grid.

I tried the solution from [Prevent content from expanding grid items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311943/prevent-content-from-expanding-grid-items) but not working. A similar question [word-wrap in a CSS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427537/word-wrap-in-a-css-grid) seems to be using tables which is outdated and not recommended in HMTL5

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bvtsan8a/23/

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: lightsalmon;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  background:peru;
}
.child{
  padding:30px;
  margin:30px;
  width:100%;
  background:indigo;
}
.item{
  background:indianred;
  padding:30px;
  margin:30px;
  width:100%;
}
.item p {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  color:gold ;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
       <p>lolololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololo
       lolololololololololololololo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use style `word-breaK:break-all` as mentioned below:

```
.item p {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  color:gold ;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvtsan8a/32/)

The reason is that `word-wrap: break-word` will only break the words. So if for an example, if your paragraph has multiple words and you want to break them then this style will be used.  And here your text inside `p` itself is one word.

While `word-break: break-all;` is used when you want to break the word.

Comment: It will be good, if you give the reason in your answer why this property is resolving the issue and not the previous one.

Comment: so you meant to say `word-wrap:break-word` won't break the single word. is that right??

Comment: `So if for an example, if your paragraph has multiple words and you want to break them then this style will be used.` In that case no need of any property. it will work automatically.

Comment: Right. In most cases it will work automatically  for `word-wrap`. But if you still want to break single word also then use `word-break`

Comment: :) :) then why this fiddle is working with only `word-wrap:break-word` https://jsfiddle.net/bvtsan8a/47/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Please check this for more clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break/

Comment: I read the thread many times. that's why i asked the above questions :)

Answer (score 3):

try using `word-break: break-word;`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: lightsalmon;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  background:peru;
}
.child{
  padding:30px;
  margin:30px;
  background:indigo;
}

.item{
  background:indianred;
  padding:30px;
  margin:30px;
}

.item p {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  color:gold ;
  word-break: break-word;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">
      <p> lolololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololololo
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```