# Automatic line breaks for too long words with CSS

Tags: css

I want to force a line break between two words if there is not enough room for both of them in just one line and between two letters if the whole word does not fit into the line. I already tried a few things but I only get them to work in Chrome. Firefox and IE break a word right between two letters although they should put one word into a new line. Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsb36w15/3/). I used this css to force line breaks.

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

You see Chrome doing line breaks just fine. IE and Firefox break the word "looooooooooooooooooooong" between two letters. How do I get those things to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table#answer-47454657).
Basically I just had to add this css code.

```
td {
    max-width: 1px;
}
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsb36w15/7/).