# Word wrap in table cell

Tags: css, html

I trying to apply word-wrap in the table cell, but it's not working.

[image]

Line wraps if file name contain space, but if space not there my table going out of div.

I also tried word-wrap and width property to table cell.

```
display: table-cell;
width: 50%;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

It works with fix width in pixels, but i can't to that because i need to manage design in all width device.

What css i can apply to make word wrap if table cell have no more space to grow ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table)

Comment: Yes. I just seen that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `word-break:break-all` instead of `word-wrap: break-word;`

```
display: table-cell;
width: 50%;
word-break:break-all;
```

```css
td {
  width:33.3%;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>largcontent_without_sapce_large_content_without_space</td>
  <td>Samll Content</td>
  <td>Test Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>largcontent_without_sapce_large_content_without_space_content_without_space</td>
  <td>Samll Content</td>
  <td>Test Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>largcontent_without_sapce_large_content_without_space</td>
  <td>Samll Content</td>
  <td>Test Content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: also consider using overflow-wrap https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: @LalitTarsariya nice to hear that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use overflow property of css in your table.

```
overflow:auto;
```

This will be working for every screen size.