# PHP/CSS: Fix the table, td size, although the text at td is too long

Tags: php, html, css

I have an issue with my table. I already set the table width and also the `th` width. But when the `td` displays data from the database, the `td` size is not as the same as set at `th`. The `td` size follows which `td` has long text. I want to make all the `td` fixed according to the width that I set. Could anyone guide me how to achieve what I am trying to do? Below is the code:

```
      echo "<table class='table table-bordered' width = '100%'>";
      echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th width = '5%'>#</th>
            <th width = '15%'>Requester</th>
            <th width = '5%'>Factory</th>
            <th width = '20%'>Room</th>
            <th width = '25%'>Purpose</th>
            <th width = '10%'>Status</th>
            <th width = '20%'>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >";

        $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM booking LEFT JOIN room ON booking.Room_ID = room.Room_ID WHERE Admin_email = '$Email' AND EndTime > GETDATE() ORDER BY booking.Book_No DESC");
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $status=$row['Book_Status'];
        if($status=="Approve")
        {
            $color="color:green";
        }
        else if($status=="Pending")
        {
            $color="color:blue";
        }
        else 
        {
            $color="color:red";
        }
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Book_No'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Requested_by'] . "</td>";                                              
            echo "<td>" . $row['Fac_ID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Room_Desc'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Meeting_Description'] . "</td>";   
            echo "<td style='$color'><strong>" . $status ."</strong></td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<a class='btn-view btn-primary btn-sm' href='../../view_booking/admin/view_booking.php?Book_No=". $row['Book_No'] ."' data-toggle='tooltip'>View</a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</tbody>";
      echo "</table><br>";
```

Comment: i think u need to use `overflow:` property on your td

Comment: add the size information in your TD tag ? You can use too word-wrap css to made it. Other thing, please take a look to prepare request to avoid SQL Injection https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php & https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: I think you can find a solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883702/6578815

Comment: did u tried the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this overflow by using css property `overflow`

**Example with overflow: scroll:**

```css
td{
  width: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Detail 1
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Detail 2
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Example with overflow: hidden**

```css
  td{
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Detail 1
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Detail 2
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Second, for suppose if you dont have space in your content having dummy content like `BLAAABLAAABLAAABLAAA` then you can use CSS [`word-wrap`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) property.

**According to W3Schools:**

you can use following properties with `overflow`:
**visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;**

**[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)**

Comment: `overflow: scroll` is all well and good, but it'll always show the bars, `overflow: auto` will show where needed when needed

Comment: @SomeRandomPerson: agreed thats way i added some reference where overflow: auto already available with example.

Comment: @devpro instead of using px, can i change to %?

Comment: @hawau yes u can