# Whole HTML document get resized to less than half the width on mobile

Tags: html, css, viewport

When I resize my webpage in browser or visit it on my phone, the  tag is like half or maybe less width of the page, the smaller the window, the bigger the gap. See screenshots below:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Some additional info: I use symfony, I have this in my code:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

The rest of the web is ok, just pages in one of my layouts are affected, but I have basically the same headers as in the other layouts, which means same styles and meta tags...

Comment: Is their some styling on the root html tag which is changing the margin/padding/width of the root element it self

Comment: We need to see your CSS and HTML mate. Just because you have the same stylesheet linked in all of your pages doesn't mean it can't contain classes messing up some sites while working on others.

Comment: I checked the stylesheets and I did not find any styles regarding nor <html> dimensions, nor margin or padding. I could provide you with the stylesheets, but it is literally hundreds of lines of code...

Comment: Did you check nasty inline-css within your HTML?

Comment: I second that you need to show at least some code. Maybe try to narrow the code to where the problem occurs, and show that? It's pretty impossible to guess.

Comment: This happens when there is an element wider then the screen width. Although the "initial scale" is specified as 1, that doesn't prevent the browser from zooming out until the widest element fits.

Comment: I can give a link to the html.twig file, but not the css. I'm sure it won't be helpful as there is just too much code to read through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that it was partly because of facebook like button, which I have placed there. Idk why, it didn't exceed any of the divs. After I deleted it, I found another problem. One of my col-xs-12s had URL address in it, which acts as a single block, which forced it to exceed its div and make a gap on the side.

Anyway, I just decided to delete the code from element to element and ultimately found out the problem, which is what matters. Solved by deleting facebook like button, that is no longer needed and shortening the URL address using twig truncate function.

Thanks to everyone, who tried to help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You need to use the [CSS word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property to force URLs to be broken if they expand outside their box. [See this example Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table?rq=1) for implementation