# text out of table when text is long, even after adding word break

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table the when text is long it's going out of table:

[image]

here the code

```html
<div class="modal-body" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
  <table id="foldersTable" class="table-hover" style=" border-collapse: collapse;   table-layout: fixed; ">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="  word-wrap: break-word;">
        <td style="word-break:  break-word;"><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i>
          <h2>aa</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="  word-wrap: break-word;">
        <td style="word-break:  break-word;"><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i>
          <h2>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="  word-wrap: break-word;">
        <td style="word-break:  break-word;"><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i>
          <h2>b</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="  word-wrap: break-word;">
        <td style="word-break:  break-word;"><i style="margin-right: 8px;" class="fa fa-folder"></i>
          <h2>cc</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table

Answer (score 1):

For word-wrap to work you should provide some width to td element and when data is more than that width it will start applying word-wrap with break-word, also you don't need to use word-wrap attribute on each and every element just use it on td and still it will work fine.