# PHP, WordWrap how to cut only text and don't cut html code

Tags: php, html, css

i have a problem.

```
wordwrap($getPagina[$i]["message"], 60, "<br/>", true)
```

I have to use the wordwrap function to not go too far with the text in a table. I inserted wordwrap and it worked fine but now that I also have to insert some html code I have a problem. The wordwrap function cuts my html code (for example span cuts it to me in sp and an) and it no longer works.
How can I do to limit the wordwrap function to plain text only avoiding html codes? Thanks

Comment: You should remove your `<br/>` option. Also, this is not the way you should be formatting your string, you would do much better to [use CSS on your table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table) to wrap the words that way (and avoiding all the mess with HTML code). [See also](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-wrap-table-cell-td-content-using-css/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You’ll want to use the `strip_tags()` function to remove HTML from your string.

```
wordwrap(strip_tags($getPagina[$i]["message"]), 60, "<br/>", true)
```

Comment: No. The tags probably need to be applied to style the text. And `strip_tags` can easily accidentally mess up strings if the HTML is not correctly formatted.

Comment: @martin Those are besides the point. The question is how to limit it to plaintext.