# Table extends off screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap class for CSS to build my asp.net MVC project and in my View The buttons go off screen and I have to scroll to see the buttons or zoom out. How to make all elements fit on the screen at any scale? On my View page I have a table with sole tr / th and buttons. I have no margins in CSS files.

[image: I have a screenshot]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
  font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
  line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
  color: var(--bs-body-color);
  text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
  background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-secondary" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
      </th>
      AND

      <td>
        <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">

          <a asp-controller="Payments" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Edit</a>
          <br/>
          <a asp-controller="Payments" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Delete</a>
        </div>
      </td>
```

Comment: Don't you have a screenshot of inspect element? I yes then post it and more than that the way you are questioning isn't right. It can be even discarded so if you have a link to that page you can attach it.

Comment: I added a screenshot where you can see the problem at the link in the post. I don’t have links to the site, because the site is on localhost. I can send link to github on this project

Comment: Neither sending us to the live site, nor referring us to an external repository, are the correct way to ask here. You need to present a [mre] of the issue, directly inside the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table simply doesn't fit the viewport. You have long words as cell contents, and you have a row of buttons. All that adds up to more width than is available.

You can do a few things:

- Increase your page width. You seem to be using a standard [container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/) instead of a fluid container. The latter eliminates unused space at the sides of the page.
- Implement [word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table) in your cells.
- Use Bootstrap's [responsive table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables) strategy to allow horizontal scroll of the table, as opposed to the entire page.
- Restructure your table to have fewer rows. Nested tables with child rows could be used to contain the action buttons.