# Grid or Table, is it possible to make the content of some cells decide the width of a column and not others?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make some cells not affect the width of a column but leave other cells to decide the width?

So far, the answers I've seen are `table-layout: fixed` but AFAIK, `table-layout: fixed` requires knowing the size of cells. I don't know the size of cells. I just know certain cells *may* be too large. So, I want the layout to work as though the content in certain cells didn't exist for width. Then I want to put content in those cells with `overflow: hidden`

Example:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| B1 | .. | B3 | B4 | B5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I don't know what content will appear in A1-A5, B1, B3-B5, C1-C5. I want the table to lay it self out like it would if there was no content at `..`

But, I actually want to put content in `..` and have it `overflow: hidden` in case it happens to be too wide

[this Q seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446624/table-cell-widths-fixing-width-wrapping-truncating-long-words) but starts with a specified width. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't specify a width.

Comment: `width: 0;min-width: 100%` to your element

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

In the cell(s) that you want to not affect the width, double wrap the content in divs

```
<td><div class="no-width">content</div></td>
```

Then use this css

```
.no-width {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid black; }

.no-width {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><td>Name</td><td>$</td></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Bob</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Jim</td><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td><div class="no-width">Alongalongalongname</div></td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Jane</td><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Elly</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cat</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Alice</td><td><div class="no-width">5444444444444444444</div></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bradly</td><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Tammy</td><td>63</td></tr>
  <tr><td><div class="no-width">tootoolong</div></td><td><div class="no-width">alsotoolong</div></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Tom</td><td>5</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```