# How can I set the max-width of a table cell using percentages?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>A long string blah blah blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
  td {
    max-width: 67%;
  }
</style>
```

The above does not work. How can I set the `max-width` of a table cell using percentages?

Comment: Please expand upon _"does not work"_.

Comment: You have to make sure the PARENT of your td has a specific width (be it that you pass width: 100%; all the way from body to your td, or you could give the parent (here: tr) 1000px or whatever you prefer. When using %% in css it always uses the exact px defined in the parent and then transforms the px into %% for the children, as they have a size _relative_ to their parent.

Comment: For the record, max-width now works in Safari and Chrome. I am not sure how long it has been supported for.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

According to the [definition of max-width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width) in the CSS 2.1 spec, “the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined.” So you cannot directly set max-width on a td element.

If you just want the second column to take up at most 67%, then you can set the width (which is in effect minimum width, for table cells) to 33%, e.g. in the example case

```
td:first-child { width: 33% ;}
```

Setting that for both columns won’t work that well, since it tends to make browsers give the columns equal width.

Comment: Actually max-width works in Safari and Chrome now. I am not sure how long it has been supported for.

Comment: @Jay, if it works, there are unknown for me conditions when it works.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD, it seems that `max-width` for `td` is respected (to some degree) if `width` is also set AND `width` and `max-width` both have either length units or percentage units. With `table-layout:fixed` it is respected without regards to the content.

Comment: Still true in the [CSS 2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-widths) Working draft

Answer (score 149):

Old question I know, but this is now possible using the css property `table-layout: fixed` on the table tag. Answer below from this question [CSS percentage width and text-overflow in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077506/css-percentage-width-and-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)

This is easily done by using `table-layout: fixed`, but a little tricky because not many people know about this CSS property.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

See it in action at the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fm5bM/4/

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid fixed means it won't recalculate the width of cells which don't have any width set, but luckily that is not the case.

Comment: @shanzilla If you have no-wrap on the cells, or the text is one unbroken string that's longer, then yes it will spill over. But using auto layout has similar and different problems as well. Just depends what you need. You can ellipses it though with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and can also add a scroll bar. CSS-Tricks as a great write up: https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Comment: I was able to use max-width on my <td> element without table-layout:fixed.

Comment: In your jsfiddle if I remove the width properties the max-width still does not work so not sure how this solves the problem.

Comment: @frezq The table needs to have a width of some sort for a percentage `max-width` to work. Having a 100% table width means it will be whatever size the container is, and the cell will always be at most 67% of it. The table is then also responsive which is a plus. Not sure how this solution wouldn't help you.

Comment: @superphonic I didn't remove the`width` property of the table, just the `width` on the `td`s. `max-width` no longer works in that case.

Comment: @frezq Seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/w3f8ey22/ - The cell with `An incredibly long name for a product intended for testing` is still 60% of the table.

Comment: @superphonic I think you're confused. If you remove the `max-width` in that jsfiddle, the width will remain the same so it's not the `max-width` that sets it. It might be clearer if you replace it with a `max-width: 10%` for the first `td`... you'll see that it does not change. http://jsfiddle.net/w3f8ey22/1/

Comment: table-layout: fixed does not solve the OP issue.  It does not magically make 'min-width' work on a table cell.  Both referenced fiddles have not difference in display if table-layout:fixed is removed.

Comment: this answer is misleading as it is not related to the question

Answer (score 9):

I know this is literally a year later, but I figured I'd share.  I was trying to do the same thing and came across this solution that worked for me.  We set a max width for the entire table, then worked with the cell sizes for the desired effect.

Put the table in its own div, then set the width, min-width, and/or max-width of the div as desired for the entire table.  Then, you can work and set width and min-widths for other cells, and max width for the div effectively working around and backwards to achieve the max width we wanted.

```css
#tablediv {
    width:90%;
    min-width:800px
    max-width:1500px;
}

.tdleft {
    width:20%;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tablediv">
  <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td class="tdleft">Test</td>
      <td>A long string blah blah blah</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Admittedly, this does not give you a "max" width of a cell per se, but it does allow some control that might work in-lieu of such an option.  Not sure if it will work for your needs.  I know it worked for our situation where we want the navigation side in the page to scale up and down to a point but for all the wide screens these days.

Comment: This is a non-answer. It does not address the OP at all.

Answer (score 1):

the percent should be relative to an absolute size,
try this :

```css
table {
  width:200px;
}

td {
  width:65%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Testasdas 3123 1 dasd as da</td>
    <td>A long string blah blah blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is to use a `div` inside the `td` with the following CSS properties:

```css
max-width: 300px; // Desired max width
width: max-content;
```

You can set the width of a different `td` to be `100%` which will take the remaining space in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my project, how cells to be dynamic width, like (`width:min-content`) behavior.
Maybe you can use this trick to limit your cell.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


 table td {
    width: 100%;
}
 table td:first-child {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
 table td:nth-child(2) {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

td:last-child {
  padding-right: unset;
}
```

```html
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td >
              <div class="">dymaic cell</div>
            </td>
            <td>one way</td>
            <td>sweater, jumper,worm</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >
              <div class="">dymaic text</div>
            </td>
            <td>one way</td>
            <td>sweater, jumper,worm</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td >
              <div class="">dymaic text ,, very long</div>
            </td>
            <td>two ways</td>
            <td>sweater, jumper,worm , jumper,worm</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

[JSFiddle preview](https://jsfiddle.net/xbe9jdz8/)

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome... just set the width attribute on the td tag.

td width=600px