# CSS percentage width and text-overflow in a table cell

Tags: css

I have a table where the cells' width is in percentage and I want to use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to hide long lines of text:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fm5bM/

In the example the ellipsis works fine in a div but not in the cell. It still grows and ignores both `width:60%` and `max-width:60%`.

If I add a `display:block` to the cell, the text does stop at 60% and gets the ellipsis, but the total width of the cell is still the size of the whole text.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fm5bM/3/

Ultimately, I want the table to fit the screen. Is there a way to do it with pure css?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is easily done by using `table-layout: fixed`, but "a little tricky" because not many people know about this CSS property.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

See it in action at the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fm5bM/4/

Comment: Thank you very much! can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Thank you was completely stuck until running into this answer.

Comment: This works with `width` but not with `max-width`.  :(