# CSS text-overflow table cell with percentage max width

Tags: html, css

I have a table with columns that have percentage widths. If the content within those cells exceeds that percentage width, I would like it to be truncated with an ellipsis.

According to [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell) I should use the max-width attribute, but according to [How can I set the max-width of a table cell using percentages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465385/how-can-i-set-the-max-width-of-a-table-cell-using-percentages) I can't do it with percentages.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
table tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
table tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 30%;
}
table tr td:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should be using a div with `column-count: 3;` [CSS3 Multiple Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: I don't see why I should- it's a table with tabular data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This cannot work with a standard HTML table: the automatic layout algorithm will keep stretching cells so they can always fit their contents, even ignoring explicit widths.

Switch to `table-layout:fixed` and [everything will work as intended](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/jmm3yr0z/).

Comment: Works great! Make sure you don't have a min-width on the table applied somewhere else in the code...

Answer (score 0):

`layout: fixed` doesn't work for all situations, and the table should be fluid and auto-space its cells, which also means setting 1% for certain cells and having others automatically adjust.

Use this: http://jsfiddle.net/maruxa1j/

Works on IE9+ too.