# How do I set max-width for a table cell?

Tags: html, css, width, max

Look at this code:

```css
#test {
  width: 20%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="test">
      <ul>
        <li>HiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiBye</li>
      </ul>
</td>
      <td>
        Box 2: Where is its 80% width?
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I set max width 20% for `#test` with **a super-long string non-broken** in it? If I set width for the second `td`, it wouldn't work!

===

Problem solved:

A line `word-break: break-all` will simply work. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You arn't closing your the `td` with id `#test`!

Comment: @pbaldauf it was closed, a silly mistake. Any suggestions how to do that? If it wasn't a duplicate, I'd be surprised that nobody has asked it before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the max-width of a table cell using percentages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465385/how-can-i-set-the-max-width-of-a-table-cell-using-percentages)

Comment: My string was too long. Did that solution worked? I didn't think that it worked for me, @uʍopǝpısdn !

Comment: I'm so sorry. It's a mistake. I didn't clarify my question. I want to do a long non-broken string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS properties `word-wrap` and `word-break` like shown below:

```css
#test {
  width: 20%; 
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="test">
      <ul>
        <li>HiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiByeHiBye</li>
      </ul>
</td>
      <td>
        Box 2: Where is its 80% width?
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```