# max-width, width not working on long text with space

Tags: html, css

I've a table with a td that contains a long string of text without any space.  I want to limit the width of the td.  But max-width (or width) is not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh6eru8p/

```
<tables>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Note:</label>
      </td>
      <td  style="max-width:30%">
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the max-width of a table cell using percentages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465385/how-can-i-set-the-max-width-of-a-table-cell-using-percentages)

Comment: Would you like to limit the number of digits in TD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed Table Cell Width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185814/fixed-table-cell-width)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to break the word using `word-break`, width will work. If you want to add `max-width` refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465385/how-can-i-set-the-max-width-of-a-table-cell-using-percentages) with `word-break`

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Note:</label>
      </td>
      <td  style="word-break: break-all;width: 42%;">
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `max-width` != `width`

Comment: I know but OP tried width:
_I've a table with a td that contains a long string of text without any space. I want to limit the width of the td. But max-width (**or width**) is not working_

Comment: fair enough. Maybe get rid of the second `tr` too while you're at it

Answer (score 1):

Width should work

apply a class name (say .one) to the td. then
add this css

```
.one {
  width: 30%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Are you trying to get the table to expand based on the content in it? Or do you want it to simply be 30%?