# Set a max-width to table cell

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to set a `max-width` css property to `table` (`td` and `th` tags).

This syntax doesn't work with me.

```
td,th{
   max-width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicated question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465385/how-can-i-set-the-max-width-of-a-table-cell-using-percentages

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `<div>` inside of each `<td>` and/or `<th>` and give it the max-width that you want.
get a look at my [working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgOKJd)

Answer (score -1):

using `table-layout: fixed` :

```
table {
  max-width: 100px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```